# Getting error of unexpected output during activation

Tags: plugin-development, errors

I have seen one plugin named [lordlinus business hours](http://wordpress.org/plugins/lord-linus-business-hours/)

When I am trying to install it, I am getting error :

> The plugin generated 2 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: That just means that there's an error during activation and that error output is activated. Please contact the plugin author on this issue.

Comment: He is not replying and I think its a good plugin, if I dont see this error

Comment: Then maybe you want to update your question with a link to the support thread and then update the support thread with a link to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same username as the plugin author? o.O

The error comes from line 444:
There's two characters between `?>` and the next `<?php`

Change:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu','business_hours_menu' );
?>

<?php

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'lordlinus_businesshour_load' );
```

To:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu','business_hours_menu' );

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'lordlinus_businesshour_load' );
```